# How to prove $r \implies (\exists x : \alpha, r)$ in Lean

Tags: logic, proof-writing, theorem-provers

I'm trying to prove the logical statement $r \implies (\exists x: \alpha, r)$, where $r$ is a `Prop` (a proposition or statement) and $\alpha$ is a `Type`. I've proved a few things in Lean, going through the exercises of the book, but I'm stuck on this one.

I'm really not sure I even understand why this is true. Wouldn't $\alpha$ being uninhabited make this a false statement since there does not exist $x \in \alpha$?

My best "attempts" were 1) hoping that lean's elaborator would fill in what I needed,

```
theorem t5_2: r → (∃ x : α, r) :=
  assume rx: r,
    ⟨_, rx⟩
```

but it can't deduce something of type $\alpha$, which makes sense. And 2) I also thought that this might be a non-constructive proof, so I was thinking of doing a proof by contradiction. However, the furthest I got on paper was
\begin{align}
  \lnot (\exists x \in \alpha, r) \implies (\forall x \in \alpha, \lnot r) \implies ??
\end{align}
I'm not sure how to perform that first implication in lean, and even if I did, I would still need an $x \in \alpha$ to eliminate the $\forall$.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: See [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/theorem_proving_in_lean.pdf), page 44 : rule $\exists$-intro is : from Prop $p(t)$ with $t$ term of type $\alpha$, infer $\exists x \ p(x)$, with $x$ of type $\alpha$.

Comment: The issue is : if $r$ is Prop with no free var $x$ inside, what is the result of the substitution $r[x \leftarrow t]$ ? It will be $r$ itself.

Comment: Thus, we may apply "vacuously" the rule to get : from Prop $r$, infer $\exists x \ r$ for $x$ of type $\alpha$ whatever. May you try with this approach ?

Comment: I can't apply the rule though because I don't have a term $t$ of type $\alpha$.

Comment: Never mind, It seems that we can assume we have access to an $x \in \alpha$. It's one of the variables listed in that section.

Comment: I do not know Lean, but my suggestion is the following : I do not think that the system will check that $t$ occurs in $p$; if so, choose an $x$ of type $\alpha$ whatever and apply the rule...